# SQL*Plus Oracle DB - Executing procedure with boolean output parameter

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to execute a stored procedure with one input (varchar) and one output (boolean) parameter from SQL*Plus.

What I have:

```
ALTER session SET nls_language='AMERICAN';
set serveroutput on;
declare bResult boolean;
exec procedureName('TEST', bResult);
/
exit;
```

What I get:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol 'end-of-file' when expecting one of the following:
begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
```

I am calling SQL*Plus from a batch script and I need to call this procedure and continue the batch script based on the results of the procedure (bResult).

In SQL Developer I can successsfully execute the procedure and return the output using the following (it doesn't work in SQL*Plus):

```
ALTER session SET nls_language='AMERICAN';
set serveroutput on;
declare bResult boolean;
begin
procedureName('TEST', bResult);
dbms_output.put_line(sys.diutil.bool_to_int(bResult));
end;
```

What can I do to make it work with SQL*Plus?

Comment: It works for me in SQL\*Plus, though I don't know what `procedureName` does or why the nls_language is important. What isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works in SQL*Plus (do not forget the ending `/`):

```
$ sqlplus system/oracle @tproc

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Jun 18 16:31:55 2020
Version 19.5.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Thu Jun 18 2020 16:31:27 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.5.0.0.0


Session altered.

SQL> --
SQL> create or replace procedure procedurename(p1 in varchar2, p2 out boolean)
  2  as
  3  begin
  4   p2 := true;
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> show errors
No errors.
SQL> 
SQL> ALTER session SET nls_language='AMERICAN';

Session altered.

SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare bResult boolean;
  2  begin
  3  procedureName('TEST', bResult);
  4  dbms_output.put_line(sys.diutil.bool_to_int(bResult));
  5  end;
  6  /
1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you but this time I am getting a different error: 'PLS-00201: identifier 'procedureName' must be declared'. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: It can mean that the procedure does not exist or that you are missing EXECUTE privilege on the procedure or that you must prefix the procedure name with the procedure owner (schema name).

Comment: You were right. Credentials used in SQL Developer were different from SQLPLUS credentials. When I used the other ones it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, You are declaring the variable using `declare`, you need to use the anonymous block as follows:

```
SQL>
SQL> ALTER session SET nls_language='AMERICAN';

Session altered.

    SQL> set serveroutput on;
    SQL> declare bResult boolean;
      2  begin -- this is needed
      3  proc('TEST', bResult); -- remove exec
      4  end;
      5  /

    PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

    SQL> exit;
    Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
    Version 19.3.0.0.0

    C:\Users\tejas.hingu>
```

Comment: Thank you but as far as I can see this solution is the same as the previous answer.